# Как зациклить карусель?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Привет, ребят, подскажите, как зациклить карусель вот эту: `jquery-waterwheel-carousel`? Зациклить в смысле, когда активен последний элемент карусели, за ним сразу идёт следующий элемент и карусель получается идёт по кругу, не перескакивая. Расковырял скрипт, но всё равно не доходит до меня, как это организовать. Буду очень признателен за ответы.

```
<a href="http://www.bkosborne.com/jquery-waterwheel-carousel">Сайт карусели</a><br>
<a htrf="https://github.com/bkosborne/jQuery-Waterwheel-Carousel">Код карусели</a>
```

Comment: открыть редактор и немного поработать до того как спрашивать

Answer (score 2):

Просто когда доходишь до конца/начала - вырезаешь первый/последний элемент и вставляешь после последнего или копируешь, после этого аналогично со следующими.

Answer (score 1):

Запихиваешь карусель в функцию и в корне функции указываешь эту же функцию

```
function Karusel () {
    Karusel(); 
}
```

Comment: аххахахахахах

Comment: гениально...

Comment: А в целом рекурсивные функции - зло!